# Adding Payment and Withdrawing system in my website using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, payment-gateway

I am writing an website using PHP-MySQL system. The website will have payment and withdraw system.

For payment, I will add paypal (mastercard/visa) as payment system. It's good. But, My question is, If someone pays to my website using Mastercard or Visa, where will the payment added? Is it to my Paypal account?

And I want to add Moneybookers, Alertpay and Paypal as withdrawal method. But, simply I don't know how to add them to my website as withdraw system. I have searched a lot to google but found nothing similar. Can anyone anchor me to a full tutorial teaching how to do so.

Odesk and similar website's are using Payment and Withdraw system. I want to add something same like them.

Comment: If you are really looking to take this further. Look at WHMCS, it's a billing tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned PayPal would handle the payment processing, and the funds would go into your PayPal account.  From there you can leave t hem in your PayPal account, or withdraw them to your bank.  You can set your account up to automatically withdraw your funds from your PayPal account each day and send them to your bank account.  If you are wanting them to be sent to multiple accounts, this would be something you would need to do manually.  If you are trying to withdraw the funds to other PayPal accounts, you could use the MassPayment API or the Adaptive Payments Pay API to send the funds to other accounts.

Comment: Thanks you very much. This helped a lot. But, what if I want to send money to any moneybookers account or any alertpay account?

Answer (score 0):

Payment amount will be credited to your paypal account and credit cart information will be handled by paypal system,

And I think its not possible to automatically withdraw an amount from any payment providers.

Comment: Odesk and similar website's are using Payment and Withdraw system. I want to add something same like them. Can I do this? If yes, how can I?